# Hide transitive dependency in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

**Project setup**: Gradle5, Spring5

We would like to use *JUnit5* as our test tool. We excluded *JUnit4* from our *Spring5* dependencies but we have a 3rd-party lib that still depends on *JUnit4*, and does not allow to exclude it. We tried to exclude *JUnit4* globally, but then our project fails to compile.

**Goal:** Our goal is to hide *JUnit4* from compile dependencies, so that developers cannot use *JUnit4* classes instead of *JUnit5* classes accidentally.

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.10.2') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:postgresql:1.7.3') {
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.11.2')
    testImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.23.0')
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
    testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
}
```

Relevant parts from our **dependencies**:

```
testCompileClasspath
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test -> 2.1.3.RELEASE
    ... (junit4 excluded)
+--- org.testcontainers:testcontainers:1.10.2
|    +--- junit:junit:4.12
|    |    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
     ...
+--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1 (*)
\--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1
```

**Desired behavior:**

```java
@Testcontainers
public class MyTestcontainersTests {

    @Container
    private PostgreSQLContainer postgresqlContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer()
            .withDatabaseName("foo")
            .withUsername("foo")
            .withPassword("secret");

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    void test() {
        org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue(postgresqlContainer.isRunning());
    }

    @org.junit.Test // compile error
    void oldTest() {
        org.junit.Assert.fail("this should be a compile error");
    }

}
```

You can find the **example code** on [github](https://github.com/kancsuki/gradle-exclude-junit4).

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. Why would you compile a library that your project depends on? And if you don't want to compile it, but only exclude it from your dependencies, then don't add it in the first place. And if you want to exclude its junit4 transitive dependency, then do it the same way as you did for spring-boot-starter-test. Your gradle build script, with comments indicating what this famous lib is, and the exact and complete error you get when executing a precise gradle command would help understanding the problem.

Comment: I modified the question and added an example to github.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a library to not be available at compile time but still present at runtime, you can simply do the following:

```
configurations {
    testImplementation {
        // Globally exclude JUnit, will not be on the testCompileClasspath thus
        exclude group: 'junit', module: 'junit'
    }
}
dependencies {
    // Make sure JUnit is on the testRuntimeClasspath
    testRuntimeOnly("junit:junit:4.12")
}
```

And if you need a similar setup for the production sources for another library, drop the `test` prefix of the configuration names and adapt the exclude and dependency coordinates.

Comment: Sadly, this does not work: When I tried to run the unit test I got `Error: cannot access org.junit.rules.TestRule  class file for org.junit.rules.TestRule not found`

Comment: Well the `@Container` annotation requires `TestRule` at compilation, so indeed it does not work, but that's because what you ask cannot work it seems. There is no built in way to selectively exclude classes from the compile classpath.

Comment: Thank you for the input. We could not find simple solution either so we went with creating a checkstyle rule that disallows `org.junit.*` until testcontainers drops the JUnit4 dependency.